# Android cursor always returning null

Tags: android, sqlite

I keep getting the following error

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

I know I have data in the database because a similar query for all the data (rather than a single entry) pulls out a list successfully

Here is my code for the database helper

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...

    public Service getMostRecentService() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1;";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    Service service = new Service();
    if(cursor != null) {
        service = new Service(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }

    return service;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I keep getting the out of bounds exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not positioned your `Cursor` on a row. Initially, it is at position -1. Presumably, given your existing code, you should call `moveToFirst()` on the `Cursor` after the `null` check and before your `getString()` calls.

Comment: oops missed that. How embarrassing